# Translate sql in linq

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

Hello I have to write in linq the sql query below:

```
Declare @OrgID int
Declare @OrgFinalID int
Set @OrgID = 91702 ---91703, 91702, 83279

select @OrgFinalID = 
        case
           when ParentOrganisationId is null then ItemID
           else ParentOrganisationId
         end
from Organisations
where ItemID = @OrgID
```

I tried to write this but I am not on the right way, sorry but I am new with LINQ:

```
var OrgID=91207;
var OrgFinalID = from o in context.Organisations 
                 where o.ItemID == OrgID
                 select new
                 {
                  o.ParentOrganisationId == null ?  o.ItemID : o.ParentOrganisationId, 
                 }
```

I have to put, with the LINQ expression, the value inside the variable OrgFinalID.

Comment: What is the datatype of the `ParentOrganisationId`  ?

Comment: ParentOrganisationId is an nvarchar

Comment: Try using the `HasValue` property.

Comment: I thought the same propery but  o.ParentOrganisationId.HasValue() , VisualStudio says that can not resolve symbol hasValue()

Comment: You are using it like method `()` just use as `o.ParentOrganisationId.HasValue`

Comment: What is your problem? The code from here seems to be correct. Do you get an error/a warning?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are expecting this to be just a single number? Than you can call `.Single()` on your query, that basically returns the value itself:

```
var OrgFinalID = (from o in context.Organisations 
                 where o.ItemID == OrgID
                 select new
                 {
                  ID = o.ParentOrganisationId == null ?  o.ItemID : Convert.ToInt32(o.ParentOrganisationId), 
                 }).Single().ID;
```

Also note call to `Convert.ToInt32` which is supported by Linq to SQL and should help you avoid type casting problem.

Other options:

- `SingleOrDefault` - if there could be single result, or no result at all (returns null in this case)
- `First` - if you expect one or more results from the query
- `FirstOrDefault` - similar to `SingleOrDefault` , returns null if no results came from the query

Comment: o.ParentOrganisationId == null ?  o.ItemID : o.ParentOrganisationId, on this error because there is not implicit conversion between int and string

Comment: @ADC, which one is which? I assume `ParentOrganisationId` is string, and `ItemID` is int, right?

Comment: yes is right. Visual STudio says this error: Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.

Comment: @ADC, I see. The problem is most likely that it is impossible to derive name of the field you are trying to create for an anonymous object.  I've slightly updated the code, see edited version

Comment: Continue to give the same error. I have tried to do this: `ID = o.ParentOrganisationId == null ? o.ItemID : int.Parse(o.ParentOrganisationId), `
There is not error but I have to test if work fine.

Comment: @ADC, updated post once more. Note that I am using a different function `Convert.ToInt32` - it is supported by Linq to SQL (unlike `int.Parse`, which is not supported afaik)

Comment: No, does not work at time of execution gives LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.int Parse'

Comment: @ADC, like I said, try `Convert.ToInt32` instead, it is supported by LInq to SQL

Comment: Also with `Convert.ToInt32` it is not supported by LINQ